# Motivation and pitfalls (?) of the auto keyword in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, type-systems

I was recently wondering why the keyword `auto` was chosen in C++11 to mark a variable whose type must be inferred by the compiler, like in

```
auto x = 1;
```

Since

1. `var` seems more common in other programming languages (e.g. C#, Scala, JavaScript), and
2. As far as I understand the new semantics of `auto` breaks backward compatibility (it was rarely used but had a different meaning in previous revisions of C++, see e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

I wanted to ask if there was a special reason for choosing `auto` (in favour of `var` or any other keyword). Was there any specific discussion about this issue before the C++11 standard was released?

Also, are there any possible incompatibilities we should watch out for when recompiling legacy C++ code with a C++11 compiler?

Comment: The new semantics of `auto` might break backwards compatibility, but, depending on how often `var` is used as a variable name compared to how often the `auto` keyword is used in pre-11 code, the committee might have opined that it breaks compatibility less dramatically than introducing a new keyword would.

Comment: @sepp2k: Good point (of course, one might have chosen another keyword as well, i.e. neither `auto` nor `var`).

Comment: @sepp2k Please make it an answer so I can upvote for you. :)

Comment: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.": This question is asking about a fact: was there a discussion about this topic. There are two possible answers: YES and NO.

Comment: Of course there was a discussion, which makes the question kinda pointless in that regard. The `auto` vs `var` question is what 90% of your text refers to, and that question has no definitive result. (though I'm not the one who has voted to close)

Comment: @Telastyn: If I had known that there had been a discussion on this topic I would not have asked. Googling for "auto versus var C++" or "auto C++" returned nothing on this topic.

Comment: Why has the question's title has been edited? It doesn't tell me what the question is right away.

Comment: The previous one looked fine: "The auto keyword in C++11" doesn't tell me anything about the question: it can be anything related to auto.

Comment: `auto` was proposed for C++ before `var` was introduced in C# so  the question should be why C# does not use auto. var has a different meaning in JavaScript and Scala

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Almost every word you might think of adding as a keyword to a language has almost certainly been used as a variable name or some other part of working code. This code would be broken if you made that word a keyword.

The incredibly lucky thing about `auto` is that it already was a keyword, so people didn't have variables with that name, but nobody used it, because it was the default. Why type:

```
auto int i=0;
```

when

```
int i=0;
```

meant exactly the same thing?

I suppose somewhere on the planet there was some small amount of code that used 'auto' the old way. But it could be fixed by removing the 'auto' and it would be working again. So it was a pretty obvious choice to repurpose the keyword.

I also happen to think it's a clearer meaning. If you've worked with variants and such, when you see `var` you may think that the declaration is somehow less strongly typed than if you pressed all the keys yourself on the keyboard to specify the type of the variable. To me, `auto` makes it clearer that you're asking the compiler to automatically deduce the type, which is just as strong as if you had specified it yourself. So it really was a very lucky break that made a good name available to the committee.

To clarify the (small) breaking:

If you had

```
auto int i=0;
```

and tried to compile with a C++ 11 compiler, you will now get an error such as

> error C3530: 'auto' cannot be combined with any other type-specifier

This is trivial, you just remove either the auto or the int and recompile.

There is a bigger problem though. If you had

```
auto i = 4.3;
```

C and the really old C++ would make `i` an `int` (as it would if you left off `auto` - default declaration was `int`). If you have gone a really long time without compiling this code, or have been using old compilers, you could have some of this code, at least in theory. C++ 11 would make it a `double` since that's what 4.3 is. (Or maybe a `float`, I'm still in Boxing Day mode, but the point is, not an `int`.) This might introduce subtle bugs throughout your app. And without any warnings or errors from the compiler. People in this boat should search globablly for `auto` to make sure they weren't using it the old way before they move to a C++ 11 compiler. Luckily, such code is extremely rare.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer.  +1  I understand the trade-off between dropping backward compatibility in a mostly harmless way and having a big chance that the old code is not broken by the new keyword.

Comment: Is there actually any incompatibility at all? Won't a C++11 compiler just ignore the `auto` if it is followed by a type name?

Comment: @eBusiness: That would be a useful piece of information!

Comment: @eBusiness the incompatibility arises with declarations like `auto i = ...`. Prior to C++11, this declares a variable with type `int`; with C++11, the compiler infers the type automatically.

Comment: Visual C++ 2012 says `error C3530: 'auto' cannot be combined with any other type-specifier` to that line

Comment: @KateGregory: Actually, there is no problem with `auto i = 4.3;`, because that was ill-formed in C++03/C++98. C++ did **not** carry over the 'implicit int' rule that C89 had (and dropped in the C99 revision).

Comment: @Kate Gregory: If you could take Bart's observations into account and change your answer accordingly I would mark it as the accepted answer.